# How to replace two sub-strings in one field and insert the result in another field in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, mysql-workbench

I have a field `oldCol` that contains string separated by `,` (comma). I just discovered that this is inconvenient as the `,`can exist in URLs. So I want to replace it with a character that can never appear in a URL like `>`:

```
https://11.com/,http://2,2.com/
https://aa.com/,https://www.bb,b.com/,http://www.abcc.org/homePage
```

The separator comma that I want to replace is placed before `http` or `https`. I do not want to change the original column. So I created a new one `newCol` and I want to set its value to the modified column. So I wrote:

```
UPDATE tbl
SET  newCol = replace(oldCol, ',https://', '>https://');
```

But the problem is that the above statement only captures `https://` and I need to also replace those with `http://` in the same time so the value of `newCol` consists of `oldCol` with separator commas converted to `>`. That is, the `newCol` in the above example is:

```
https://11.com/>http://2,2.com/
https://aa.com/>https://www.bb,b.com/>http://www.abcc.org/homePage
```

Comment: Before getting fancy, what’s the problem with  running separate queries, one `where oldCol like '%http:%'` and one for `'%https:%'`? And btw I once created an endpoint that accepted expressions, which could contain both `<` and `>`. Maybe a tab char is a more solid choice

Comment: Thanks. But using tab is not suitable as I need a single character since this column is already used in some queries with complex regex. I just want to replace comma with `>`. It is not possible to make two `UPDATE SET` queries. Each `SET` will override the previous. So if I `UPDATE SET` the right value of the column should be prepared in one shot. It is like `INSERT`. Finally, Isorry I do not get what you mean by `btw I once created an endpoint that accepted expressions, which could contain both < and >`. Does using `>` caused you a problem before? What was it? Plz, clarify.

Comment: @Bohemian plz check the question. I do not want to just query. No I want to modify a column and insert the modified column in a new column.

Comment: If you add a where clause you won’t “update twice”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace twice:

```
UPDATE tbl
    SET newCol = replace(replace(oldCol, ',https://', '>https://'), ',http://', '>http://');
```